# Magento 2.3.4 - Category save issue after upgrade

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, admin, category

I just upgrade the store from Magento 2.3.3 version to Magento 2.3.4 version and I can't save any category in backend:

[image]

and in the debug.log file I have this error:

```
[2020-03-09 10:44:04] main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to a member function getAttributeCode() on bool in /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Observer/InvalidateCacheOnCategoryDesignChange.php:67
Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): Magento\Catalog\Observer\InvalidateCacheOnCategoryDesignChange->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#1 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(74): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\Catalog\Observer\InvalidateCacheOnCategoryDesignChange), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#2 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#3 /chroot/home/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#4 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EventManager.php(51): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#5 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Update.php(110): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EventManager->dispatchEntityEvent('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save_after', Array)
#6 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php(96): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Update->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor), Array)
#7 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category.php(1124): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#8 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#9 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->___callParent('save', Array)
#10 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Category.php(44): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#11 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Category.php(28): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Category->addCommitCallback(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#12 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Category->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#13 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/FlushCacheByTags.php(69): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#14 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\FlushCacheByTags->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#15 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#16 /chroot/home/html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category/Interceptor.php(364): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)
#17 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(655): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#18 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
#19 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor->___callParent('save', Array)
#20 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#21 /chroot/home/html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category/Interceptor.php(1547): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)
#22 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Save.php(232): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor->save()
#23 /chroot/home/html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Save/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save->execute()
#24 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(108): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->execute()
#25 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(231): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#28 /chroot/home/html/app/code/WeltPixel/Backend/Plugin/Utility.php(76): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): WeltPixel\Backend\Plugin\Utility->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /chroot/home/html/app/code/WeltPixel/Backend/Plugin/Utility.php(76): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): WeltPixel\Backend\Plugin\Utility->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /chroot/home/html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Save/Interceptor.php(65): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#36 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(159): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(98): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor))
#38 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#40 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#41 /chroot/home/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#42 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#43 /chroot/home/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#44 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#45 /chroot/home/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#46 {main} [] []
```

How I can find what is wrong there? I mention that in the M2.3.3 version everything was work fine.

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**

I have there in the admin of categories a custom attribute, I add this attribute and I add the following code in: HS/GroupedProduct/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
         <field name="edream_short_description">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Short Description</item>
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons1" xsi:type="string">bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons2" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons3" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons4" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="files_browser_window_url" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                        <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">edream_short_description</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

is something wrong with this?

[image]

**Edit:**
if I comment out this lines of code everything is working fine and the category save is working perfect. It is a **Magento 2.3.4 BUG**?

```
       if ($this->isCategoryAttributeChanged($designAttribute->getAttributeCode(), $category)) {
            $this->cacheTypeList->invalidate(
                [
                    \Magento\PageCache\Model\Cache\Type::TYPE_IDENTIFIER,
                    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Layout::TYPE_IDENTIFIER
                ] 
            );
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Any fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error may be custom attribute then you can find this way..
**Go to Below file and uncomment below line** 
1) **app/bootstrap.php**, there is:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

2) Run below commands

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

and you can replace wysiwyg attribute with this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">

        <field name="edream_short_description">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons1" xsi:type="string">bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons2" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons3" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons4" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="files_browser_window_url" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                        <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">edream_short_description</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Short Description</item>
                    <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true"></item>
                    <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string"></item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="title_new">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">120</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
                    <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true"></item>
                    <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string"></item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, and after this? where I can see the errors?

Comment: aa I found the error: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\FileInfo::removeStorePath() must be of the type string, array given, called in /chroot/home/a593d01f/heatshieldproducts.com/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/FileInfo.php on line 167

and how I can fix this?

Comment: @Robert i think issue is custom attribute you can check ..

Comment: Hi again, can you check, I edit my post

Comment: @Robert you need wysiwyg attribute?

Comment: yes will be fine to be, so one wysiwyg attribute and other text attribute (the same like Category Name).

Comment: @Robert i have updated my answer

Comment: thank you so much, let me try, and also I have a text attribute with the name title_new for categories, how I can call this one too?

Comment: and please check again I add a screenshot to my post, I don't have that Use Default Value checkbox, when change the Store View

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105354/discussion-between-rakesh-donga-and-robert).

Comment: Hi again, I use this to view all category attributes: SELECT *
FROM `eav_attribute`
WHERE `entity_type_id` = '3', I delete all custom attributes, and I have the same error, main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to a member function getAttributeCode() on bool in /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/magento/module-catalog/Observer/InvalidateCacheOnCategoryDesignChange.php:67

Answer (score 0):

This is my debug after the error. I don't find what's wrong. And..i dont have a file GroupedProduct/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
[2020-03-11 08:02:45] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor" [] []
[2020-03-11 08:02:56] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"https://mysite/myadmin/catalog/category/save/key/9faa93e5a338bc75f129d718c1d4edab5d3d67b3a8f070974ae7c42640c17588/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["cat_c"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}} []
[2020-03-11 08:02:56] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"https://mysite/myadmin/catalog/category/save/key/9faa93e5a338bc75f129d718c1d4edab5d3d67b3a8f070974ae7c42640c17588/","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Uri: http://86.109.18.117:8080/)"],"formattedTagsChunk":"((^|,)cat_c_6(,|$))|((^|,)cat_c_p_6(,|$))"}} []
[2020-03-11 08:02:56] main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to a member function getAttributeCode() on boolean in /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Observer/InvalidateCacheOnCategoryDesignChange.php:67
Stack trace:
#0 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): Magento\Catalog\Observer\InvalidateCacheOnCategoryDesignChange->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#1 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(74): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\Catalog\Observer\InvalidateCacheOnCategoryDesignChange), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#2 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#3 /home/magentositest1/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#4 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EventManager.php(52): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#5 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Update.php(110): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EventManager->dispatchEntityEvent('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save_after', Array)
#6 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php(96): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Update->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor), Array)
#7 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category.php(1124): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#8 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#9 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->___callParent('save', Array)
#10 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Category.php(44): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#11 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Category.php(28): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Category->addCommitCallback(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#12 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Category->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#13 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/FlushCacheByTags.php(69): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#14 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\FlushCacheByTags->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#15 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#16 /home/magentositest1/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category/Interceptor.php(364): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)
#17 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(655): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#18 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
#19 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor->___callParent('save', Array)
#20 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#21 /home/magentositest1/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category/Interceptor.php(1547): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)
#22 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Save.php(232): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor->save()
#23 /home/magentositest1/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Save/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save->execute()
#24 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(108): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->execute()
#25 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(231): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#28 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /home/magentositest1/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Save/Interceptor.php(65): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#32 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(159): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save\Interceptor))
#34 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#36 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /home/magentositest1/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#38 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 /home/magentositest1/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#40 /home/magentositest1/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#41 /home/magentositest1/magento2/pub/index.php(40): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#42 {main} [] []
```